# Using hashcat where first 10 character of hash are known

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hashcat

I've web application that use MySQL

The application use password hash function from MySQL to store the password for related account

The problem is, it trim the hashed password so that it only store first 10 characters into the password field

I want to prove to my supervisor that, trimming hashed password can make different password to be entered on the login form and accepted by the application. Because those passwords has same first 10 character

To prove that, I'm planning to use hashcat. I've download quite big dictionary file to help my purpose

So, is there someone can help me how is the parameter that I should use in hashcat?

I've tried to google for the answer, but no luck

Thanks

Comment: I wrote a small script to find a collision for you, see my [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55742021/6770384). Writing the script took ten minutes and running it two seconds. But even with untrimmed hashes using MySQL's `Password()` function (which is basically two times sha1) seems insecure. Your supervisor should read up on that topic. Maybe [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/126301) helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an answer to the actual question skip to the last section of this answer. The other sections do not answer your question directly, but you may find that this is not neccessary anymore after reading them.

---

## Your Description Of The System

You said the system processes the password as follows
`plaintext password` ➜ `hashed password` ➜ `first 10 characters of the hash`

**Example:**
`Topsecret123` ➜ `*E7C95D33E14D3C2A3AE4EAB25C1D98C88593F7AC` ➜ `*E7C95D33E`

Note that [MySQL's `PASSWORD()` prefixes hashes with a `*`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/98529), so you actually only include 9 characters from the hash.

---

## Answering The Question In The Background

You asked how to find hash collisions for the approach from above using hashcat, but what you actually wanted to know/show was

> prove trimming hashed password can make different password [...] accepted by the application.

Your emphasis was on »**Trimming** causes multiple passwords to be accepted«. However, you overlooked that even untrimmed hashing causes multiple passwords to be accepted.

#### The Pigeonhole Principle

The explanation is so simple that you don't have to find a hash collision. Everyone should understand the following:

- There is an infinite amount of passwords.
- MySQL password hashes have a fixed length, precisely 64 bit. There can be only 2<sup>64</sup> different hashes.
- The password hash function maps passwords to hashes. Since there are more passwords than hashes some passwords have to be mapped to the same hash.
  <sub>If not, you would have found a compression function which would allow you to store *anything* in only 64 bits.</sub>

One may argue that the number of valid passwords is not infinite. But even if you would limit valid passwords to be of exactly length 11 and contain only symbols from the group `[A-Za-z0-9]` (has 62 symbols) there would be 62<sup>11</sup> unique passwords:

62<sup>11</sup> ≈ 5,2×10<sup>19</sup>  passwords
  2<sup>64</sup> ≈ 1,8×10<sup>19</sup> hashes

Therefore, there still have to be lots of collisions.

#### Hash Collisions

Trimming hashes is not the root cause of the collision problem, but of course it increases the likelihood of collisions enormously. Normally, hash collisions are not a problem because they happen so rarely that you don't encounter them. However, with strongly trimmed hashes like yours, collisions become a real problem.

---

## Finding A Collision

#### Using Hashcat

hashcat can compute MySQL password hashes with `-m 300`. You can confirm this by [computing `SELECT Password("hashcat");`](https://paiza.io/projects/e/9yul5PJlG3mweeijCmUzwA) and comparing the resulting hash with the hash shown [here](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes).

However, I couldn't find a way to trim these hashes / look for prefix collisions. I guess **hashcat cannot do what you want**. You would have to implement a custom hashmode for hashcat. The easiest way to do this would be to alter the [current implementation of hashcat's MySQL mode](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/blob/master/src/modules/module_00300.c). I'm not sure, but maybe it is sufficient to just change [`const int out_len = 40;`](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/blob/master/src/modules/module_00300.c#L130) to `9`. You may have to update the OpenCL versions of the same module too. Search for `m00300` [here](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/tree/master/OpenCL).

#### Using A Custom Script

Alternatively, look for a list of password-hash-pairs or generate one yourself, then look for prefix collisions in that table. This was fun so I did it myself

The following python program generates trimmed hashes for some numerical passwords:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import hashlib as hl

def mySqlPwHash(password):
        return hl.sha1(hl.sha1(password.encode()).digest()).hexdigest()[:9]

for number in range(0, 300000):
        password = str(number)
        print(password, "\t", mySqlPwHash(password))
```

I chose to generate 300'000 hashes because there are 16<sup>9</sup> trimmed hashes and we can expect to find a collision in √(16<sup>9</sup>) = 262'144 tries (see [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

To find passwords with the same hash run the script as follows:

```
./collide.py | sort -k2 | uniq -Df1
```

In only two seconds the script finished and printed

```
23607    47ae310ff
251848   47ae310ff
```

And there you have it, two passwords (`23607` and `251848`) with the same trimmed hash (`47ae310ff`).

If your trimmed hashes actually include 10 hex-digits you can adapt the script and will find the two passwords `1874547` and `2873667` sharing the hash `47fc464b2f`.

Comment: Thank you for your complete explanation. It'll open my supervisor mind for sure